# Using Objective-C framework in SwiftUi application

Tags: objective-c, swiftui

This is my first Swift project. I did some Objective-C in the past, but I'm only just starting with Swift. I want to use the ConnectSDK within this SwiftUI project. I've created a bridging header and add some imports for a few of the headers in the SDK. With only these changes, the project builds. I'm stuck on how to make calls to the SDK from SwiftUI. Here's what I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI
import ConnectSDK

struct ContentView: View {
        
    class ConnectSDKHelper {
        func showDevicePicker () {
            let dm = DiscoveryManager.shared()
            dm?.startDiscovery()
            dm?.devicePicker()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
           
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Through some googling, I found that I might need a helper class, hence ConnectSDKHelper, but I don't know if this even correct, or how to apply it if it is. If I try to initialize a ConnectSDK object,

```
    var body: some View {
        let helper = ConnectSDKHelper()
        VStack {
            helper.showDevicePicker()
           
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
```

I could use a little help here, and if there is some tutorial on how to use ObjC frameworks in SwiftUI, please point me to them. The examples I've found are just a bit too trivial.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot put procedural code like that in the view hierarchy. Use `onAppear` or `task`.  You may want to check out a SwiftUI tutorial (Apple or Hacking with Swift) to get the basics of the framework.

Comment: `VStack` expects `Views`. While from the name of `showDevicePicker()`, that's an action. You can't do it like that as said. You need to understand that SwiftUI is a framework for UI, and if you want to trigger action on button, on view appearing, there are specific methods for that (like `onAppear()` as said previously).

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Further research is required. Thanks